# how to push your project on github

Tags: symfony, github

I start on github but I have a problem I can not push my project in my repository I get this error, what to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have 2FA activated. In this case, you need to use [a special token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/accessing-github-using-two-factor-authentication#using-two-factor-authentication-with-the-command-line) instead of your password to be able to log into Github through the command line.

Then, you should be able to push on Github.

Comment: I don't know what a 2FA?

Comment: 2FA = Two Factor Authentication